# Loading keras model into tensorflow.js locally

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

I want to load `keras` model which has been converted into `tensorflow.js` compatible format to perform inference.
My code looks like this

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime.js";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

const model_path = '/home/user/Desktop/Github/tfjs_model/tfjs/tfjs_model/model.json'; 

async function loadModel(path){
  console.log("Model loading in progress from ".concat(path));
  const model =  await tf.loadLayersModel(path);
  console.log("Model Loaded Successfully");
  return model;
};

const model = loadModel(model_path);

const input = tf.tensor1d([1], [13]);
console.log(model.predict(input));
```

I am getting this error
`Error: Failed to parse model JSON of response from /home/user/Desktop/Github/tfjs_model/tfjs/tfjs_model/model.json'. Please make sure the server is serving valid JSON for this request.`

I've looked in a lot of placed (Github issues, Stack overflow) but can't seem to find a fix. How can this be resolved ?
`

Comment: can you share your json?

Comment: I suspect that your server cannot actually serve that file path. Can you try to copy the `model.json` file to where your `index.html` is then change the `model_path` to `model.json`?

Comment: I changed `model_path` to `model.json` and kept both the files (bin and json) where index,html is. It's still not resolved. I'm using parceljs. I get this

Comment: Oh you are using parceljs. Have a look at this issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/924 you might have to install some plugins.

Comment: may be your path is wrong.

Comment: I created a static folder and kept both the files inside `static`. My model_path is now `'static/model.json'`. It still doesn't work.

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials/conversion/import_keras#step_2_load_the_model_into_tensorflowjs

Comment: I've followed this tutorial. It doesn't say anything about how to load files with parcel js. If you see my code above, It's identical.

Comment: @kl_divergence, have you changed the content of the `json` file ? The error is not that it can't find the file. The error is that the server cannot parse the json file which indicates that the file content is possibly not a valid json

Comment: I did not change the json file. I uploaded it online and loading the model from URL works fine. I'm not able to do this locally.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too.

Using `const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('directory/model.json');` generated the same error you had. I tried changing the import to find file `model2.json`, which didn't exist yet gave the same error (I notice there's an outstanding issue with TensorFlow.js to give a more meaningful error).

Looking at my Parcel setup, I realised that the `model.json` and `.bin` files were being copied into the root of the `dist` folder. So I removed the directory from the import and now it works with:

`const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('model.json');`

Note that my files are still in `<content_root>/directory/`.